# Django model form field to have a user dropdown list based on a condition

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

In a Django Modelform (Product_definition), i want to have a dropdown(Merchant name) which will show users only if the their designation in User form is "Merchant". 
is it possible that I could get the list of users for the dropdown based on this condition .Please note that i don't require it to be a foreign key as connecting the models is not required. 
This is the form which contains the Designation :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    #extra UserAttribute
    MERCHANT = 'MR'
    FABRIC = 'FR'
    WASHING = 'WS'
    PRINT = 'PR'
    PLANNER = 'PL'

    DESIGNATION_CHOICES =(
        (PLANNER,'Planner'),
        (MERCHANT,'Merchant'),
        (FABRIC,'Fabric'),
        (WASHING,'Washing'),
        (PRINT,'Printing'),

    )

    Designation =models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = DESIGNATION_CHOICES,
        default= 'PLANNER'
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and this is the form with Merchant Name where I want the names of all merchants to appear.

```
class Product_definition(models.Model):

Order_number = models.CharField(max_length=25,unique = True, blank = True, null = True)
style_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank = True, null = True)
color = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank = True, null = True)
Order_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField()
SMV = models.FloatField()
MERCHANT = models.ForeignKey(UserProfileInfo,on_delete= models.CASCADE,default='Select')
def __str__(self):
    return self.Order_number
```

I have created a foreign key for now but I don't require it and it doesn't list the names of only the merchant in the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):  # please use CamelCase when defining Class Names
    MERCHANT = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(Designation=UserProfileInfo.MARCHENT))  # Please use sname_case when naming attributes
    class Meta:
       model = Product_definition  # Please use CamelCase when defining model class name
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: When trying to migrate i am getting "invalid literal for int () with base 10" . Before adding this form I was able to migrate. I have also replaced all the integer field to FloatField but it didn't resolve the error